# how to set default time for fullcalendar in month view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar from http://fullcalendar.io

I have it setup for only selecting slots between 9am-5pm, although when in **month view** if a day is clicked it automatically tries to schedule for 12:00am (00:00:00) --- is there a way to set the default time on month view to 9am ?

my config:

```
        $calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            height: 475,
            defaultDate: moment(),
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            minTime: "09:00:00",
            maxTime: "17:00:00",
            titleFormat: "MMMM D, YYYY",
            columnFormat: "ddd. MMMM D",
            weekends: false,
            editable: false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            eventOverlap: false,
            eventDurationEditable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventSources: ['events.php'],
            timeFormat: 'h:mm',
            businessHours: { start: '09:00', end: '17:00' }
});
```

*EDIT* - I found a small solution by doing what i posted below but i'm wondering if there is another way around in the configuration?

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var time = moment(date).format('HH:mm:ss');

    if (time == "00:00:00") {
        date = moment(date).set('hour', 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing the select callback. How is selection even working (on any view)? There must be some code you left out.

Comment: I think, it's intended behaviour: from the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/): "If an all-day area has been clicked, the moment will be ambiguously-timed. Therefore you should better check for view.type == "month" in the dayClick method.